# RethinkDB: Equivalent for "select where field not in (items)"

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a table that looks like this:

```
[                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    { "name": "Alpha", "values": {                                                                                                                                                                             
        "someProperty": 1                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }},                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    { "name": "Beta", "values": {                                                                                                                                                                              
        "someProperty": 2                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }},                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    { "name": "Gamma", "values": {                                                                                                                                                                             
        "someProperty": 3                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }}                                                                                                                                                                                                         
]
```

I want to select all records where `someProperty` is not in some array of values (e.g., all records where `someProperty` not in `[1, 2]`). I want to get back complete records, not just the values of `someProperty`.

How should I do this with RethinkDB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python it would be:

```
table.filter(lambda doc: r.not(r.expr([1,2]).contains(doc["someProperty"]))
```

---

If the array comes from a subquery and you don't want to do it multiple times:

```
subquery.do(lambda array:
    table.filter(lambda doc: r.not(array.contains(doc["someProperty"]))))
```

Comment: What would be the most efficient way to do this if the array of values I want to filter out comes from a subquery? It looks like simply replacing r.expr(...) with the subquery would run the subquery for every document.